# What's the "rails way" to access a resource in a controller's before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, pundit

I'm using Pundit to authorize actions in my controllers. My first try was to authorize the model in an after_action hoook:

```
class CompaniesController < InheritedResources::Base
  after_action :authorize_company, except: :index

  def authorize_company
    authorize @company
  end
```

This let me use the default controller actions which define `@company` so I wouldn't hit the database twice. But, this is bad for destructive actions because it's going to not authorize the action *after* I've already messed up the database.

So, I've changed to using a `before_action` hook:

```
class CompaniesController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_action :authorize_company, except: :index

  def authorize_company
    @company = Company.find(params.require(:id))
    authorize @company
  end
```

Now, I'm not allowing unauthorized people to delete resources, etc... but I'm hitting the database twice. Is there anyway to access `@company` without hitting the database twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your asking for the "rails way" this is how you would set this up in "plain old rails" without `InheritedResources`.

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_company, except: [:new, :index]

  def new
    @company = authorize(Company.new)
  end

  def index
    @companies = policy_scope(Company)
  end

  # ...

  private

  def authorize_company
    @company = authorize(Company.find(params[:id]))
  end
end
```

If you *really* want to use callbacks you would do it like so:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_company, except: [:new, :index]
  before_action :authorize_companies, only: [:index]
  before_action :build_company, only: [:new]

  # ...

  private

  def authorize_company
    @company = authorize(Company.find(params[:id]))
  end

  def authorize_companies
    @companies = policy_scope(Company)
  end

  def build_companies
    @company = authorize(Company.new)
  end
end
```

Yeah you could write a single callback method with three code branches but this has lower cyclic complexity and each method does a single job.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out rails controllers have a `resource` if the model exists and `build_resource` for actions like `new`.

```
class CompaniesController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_action :authorize_company, except: :index

  private

    def authorize_company
      authorize resource
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      authorize build_resource
    end
end
```

Comment: Thats more likely a method of InheritedResources and not Rails.

Comment: And don't do this. `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` will be raised if the passed id is not a valid id which is something that will happed in your application if a resource is deleted and somebody follows an old link. Instead of returning the error page and a 404 you're now rendering the show page with a new (blank) resource and will get nil errors galore.